# What is the meaning behind this Foxtrot comic?

Tags: comics

My children were reading my old Foxtrot book and asked me to explain this particular strip and I’m not quite sure of the punch line. My initial assumption is that it’s a reference to a movie but some Googling didn’t come up with anything.

Any ideas on this, or is it just the idea of leaving your sister stranded with a large sum of money?? I noticed there is a show called ‘Stranded with a million dollars’ (2017) but the comic was written in 2002 which doesn’t align.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the comments on the [comic's page](https://www.gocomics.com/foxtrot/2000/07/16) on GoComics suggest, it's potentially a reference to the show [Survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_(American_TV_series)), specifically the US version which first aired on May 31, 2000, about a month and a half before the comic's publication date of July 16th (which allows enough time for the show to demonstrate its popularity and Amend to write the comic in time for publication).

Assuming that this is correct, then the explanation of the punchline is something along the lines of:

- Paige was stranded on a desert island but managed to survive;
- Her brother (presumably Jason) learned of this, but instead of trying to rescue her instead turned her predicament into a reality show premise;
- Having made a large amount of money selling the premise for "Survivor", he then writes Paige a check for million dollars as her cut; and
- He has this check delivered to her, still on the deserted island, and still not making any effort to rescue her.

Comment: Looks like the question was closed due to being off topic (I couldn’t find anywhere better to post it) but I greatly appreciate knowing now Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This comic came out just as the show *Survivor* got popular, where, to put it most simply, the contestants receive money for being stranded on a desert island with few supplies.

So Paige thinks she is on *Survivor*.  She has been stranded on a desert island and received a check for a million dollars for it (of course, this isn't how the show works; one receives the prize money after returning home, but no matter).

As the boat that dropped her off leaves, she examines the check--Jason's name is on it.  Jason does not have a million dollars--the check, and show, is fake.  Jason has somehow tricked Paige into voluntarily being stranded on a desert island for no actual benefit.  In addition, she shares the island not with the contestants and crew of *Survivor*, but with nobody but hundreds of rats, as Paige will learn to her disgust and horror as soon as she turns around.

As it relies on a misunderstanding or willful misinterpretation of the *Survivor*  concept, and is kind of weird to begin with (where did Jason get the boat?) I can see why it would be hard to understand

Comment: You know what, I think your answer might be right. It's definitely a Survivor reference, but the punchline is ... a bit vague and up for interpretation.